# Rails(3.2.2) Direct sign_in to the Spree(1.1.1) from non-spree controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have integrated Spree(1.1.1) into my existing Rails 3.2.2 Application. I have home_controller in my existing application. I want to direct login the user from action in the home controller to the spree using the sign_in method as

```
user = Spree::User.find(params[:user_id])
sign_in(user)
```

but that sign_in method is in the context of Spree.

How should I use sign_in. ?

Answer (score 0):

The `sign_in` method is from Devise. You can use this method in any controller of your application.

Comment: Yes! Right...I have integrated Spree(1.1.1) into existing Rails 3.2.2 app. It already has its own authentication system. If I would have used sign_in from my existing app's controller it would have called the application's login method not for Spree. Finally I created custom action in the Spree's controller and in that action I called sign_in to sign in into Spree and it worked! the problem was related to before filter in the Spree's controller :) thanks for the reply